# Real Time filtering of the ListBox

Tags: wpf, filter, textbox, listbox

Short background on the problem:
I am working on the UI part of an WPF application. But since I have finished my part pretty fast - decided to try implement ListBox filtering function.

What I have at this point:

```
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkMessageTextBoxStyle}" 
             x:Name="usuariosDisponiblesSearch" 
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTable}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"                 
             AlternationCount="2" 
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
             x:Name="lbPossibleContracts" 
             SelectionChanged="lbPossibleContracts_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

TextBox contains a searching string.
ListBox - reflects data, picked from the DB by field Nombre.

On the end point - I want to have working filter, which shows in the ListBox only the items, which match with the string in the TextBox. Real time.

Of course, I understand that it is impossible to do, without modifying the back code.

The problem is that so far my approaches for implementation of filtering functionality were unsuccessful, mainly because I didn't understood what exactly I am implementing into the back code.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Works in any direction - if you want produce the whole part of code ( :) ) - you are welcomed, if you have some good, understandable reference to an equal, solved problem -it is great as well.

UPDATE

Ok, I have made some pretty huge progress in the subject.

I was following this example: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/

Here are the codes:

```
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkMessageTextBoxStyle}" 
             x:Name="usuariosDisponiblesSearch" 
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
             TextChanged="usuariosDisponiblesSearch_TextChanged" />
        <ListBox  Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTable}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              Margin="0,20,0,0"
              x:Name="lbPossibleContractsFilter" 
              SelectionChanged="lbPossibleContracts_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And here is the backcode:

```
public partial class ProjectAssignUsuariosView : UserControl
{
    private ProjectAssignUsuariosViewModel _viewModel;



    public ProjectAssignUsuariosView(Proyecto proyecto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new ProjectAssignUsuariosViewModel(proyecto);

        //TempFilterPart
        lbPossibleContractsFilter.ItemsSource = _viewModel.UsuariosLibres;
        List<Usuario> items = new List<Usuario>();
        filteredUsers.ItemsSource = items;
        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbPossibleContractsFilter.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = UserFilter;
        //Filtering part ends
    }

    //Filtering
    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usuariosDisponiblesSearch.Text))
            return true;
        else
            return ((item as Usuario).Nombre.IndexOf(usuariosDisponiblesSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }


    private void usuariosDisponiblesSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbPossibleContractsFilter.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
    //Filtering ends
```

No errors while compiling. But when running and change the TextBox - throws Unexpected application error. And the debuger says "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Try searching SO for filtering with CollectionViewSource

Comment: Sounds like a great start! Quick question - what stands behind SO? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This site, stackoverflow

Comment: It was the end of the working day and I knew that it is something obvious :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have made a stable working prototype for described purpose.
I was following this example: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/
The only difference is that my ItemsSource had been placed outside.

Here are the working codes (simplified).

XAML:

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTable}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"                 
             AlternationCount="2" 
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
             x:Name="lbPossibleContracts" 
             SelectionChanged="lbPossibleContracts_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Important parts here are the ListBox x:Name Property, which gives access to the ItemsSource. And ListBox SelectionChanged Propert, which calls for refresh of the results.

XAML.CS:

```
namespace Todiste.Views.Proyectos
{
public partial class ProjectAssignUsuariosView : UserControl
{
    private ProjectAssignUsuariosViewModel _viewModel;
    public ProjectAssignUsuariosView(Proyecto proyecto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new ProjectAssignUsuariosViewModel(proyecto);

        lbCurrentContracts.ItemsSource = _viewModel.UsuariosProyecto;
        lbPossibleContracts.ItemsSource = _viewModel.UsuariosLibres;
        //Filter Starts            
        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbPossibleContracts.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = UserFilter;
        //Filter Ends
    }

    //Filter Starts
    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Text))
            return true;
        else
            return ((item as Usuario).Nombre.IndexOf(filter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }

    private void filter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbPossibleContracts.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
    // Filter Ends
```

Here are three main points, worth attention:

1. lbPossibleContracts.ItemsSource = _viewModel.UsuariosLibres; - assigning outside datasource to the list
2. Collection view =  - defining, the view
3. UserFilter and filter_TextChanged - are actually the functions, which are performing filtering and list refreshing actions

Not the best style, but a working one.